# Is there any Android MVC Framework?

Tags: java, android, model-view-controller, frameworks

I have been searching trough this site but all the replies are old and we all know who programming changes, therefore, I would like to know if there is currently any MVC Framework for Android, as we can find SpringMVC for JEE applications, I wonder if there is something similar for Android.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a [Spring port](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android) for Android.

You could also have a look at the [android.arch.*](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) packages, specifically [ViewModel](https://medium.com/google-developers/viewmodels-persistence-onsaveinstancestate-restoring-ui-state-and-loaders-fc7cc4a6c090) and LiveData which might be easier to use for this purpose.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html